# Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range. Not getting a value from array in swift, console shows they're not empty arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I get a:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range

when I call a function.

I have a function that should perform a comparison between values stored into 2 CLLocation2D arrays. The first,`trackingRouteArray`, gets CLLocation2D appended by monitoring user position. The second, `alertNotificationArray`, gets appended by double taps that store the CLLocation2D.

I have two counters `trackingCoordinatesArrayPosition`and `alertNotificationArrayPosition` that are used to increment array position to get values from.

Now my problem is that the `trackingRouteArray` has a value when I refer to its positions, but `alertNotificationArray`doesn't.
In the console I print both arrays and they are both populated with values.

Here's the code:

```
func checkAlerts() {
    while trackingCoordinatesArrayPosition != ( (trackingCoordinatesArray.count) - 1) {
        let trackingLatitude = trackingCoordinatesArray[trackingCoordinatesArrayPosition].latitude
        let trackingLongitude = trackingCoordinatesArray[trackingCoordinatesArrayPosition].longitude
        let alertLatitude = alertNotificationArray[alertNotificationArrayPosition].latitude
        let alertLongitude = alertNotificationArray[alertNotificationArrayPosition].longitude

        if trackingLatitude == alertLatitude && trackingLongitude == alertLongitude {
            // do something
            print( "found problem")
        }
        else if alertNotificationArrayPosition < alertNotificationArray.count {
            alertNotificationArrayPosition = alertNotificationArrayPosition + 1
        }
        else if  alertNotificationArrayPosition == alertNotificationArray.count {
            trackingCoordinatesArrayPosition = ( trackingCoordinatesArrayPosition + 1)
            alertNotificationArrayPosition = 0
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error on the `let alertLatitude = alertNotificationArray[alertNotificationArrayPosition].latitude`line

These are the prints from console:

> tracking stopped
>   alerts coordinates are[__C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.333775436275886, longitude: -122.02368602396592), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.332980802736785, longitude: -122.02355882939459), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.333891009356435, longitude: -122.0235224889466), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.33415106952107, longitude: -122.02355883066487), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.334338890591638, longitude: -122.02332261163552), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.334598949139817, longitude: -122.02328627075829), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.335696975135136, longitude: -122.0236315182422)]
>   route coordinates are[__C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.333153109999998, longitude: -122.02360022000001), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.333184799999998, longitude: -122.02360543), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.333217210000001, longitude: -122.02360829), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.333247679999999, longitude: -122.02360903), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.333278159999999, longitude: -122.02360912), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.333308330000001, longitude: -122.02360862), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.333339840000001, longitude: -122.02360667000001), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.333372369999999, longitude: -122.02360458), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.333404880000003, longitude: -122.02360226), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.333437250000003, longitude: -122.02360114), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.333469319999999, longitude: -122.02360106), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.333500979999997, longitude: -122.0236012), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.333533869999997, longitude: -122.02360059999999), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.333567180000003, longitude: -122.02360006000001), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.333599149999998, longitude: -122.02359964999999), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.333630999999997, longitude: -122.0236005), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.333663510000001, longitude: -122.02360109), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.33369742, longitude: -122.02360057999999), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.33373237, longitude: -122.02359865), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.333768640000002, longitude: -122.0235964), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.333807470000004, longitude: -122.02359255), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.333850239999997, longitude: -122.02359082), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.333894520000001, longitude: -122.02358845000001), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.333937650000003, longitude: -122.02358579), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.333980240000002, longitude: -122.02358187999999), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.334027380000002, longitude: -122.02357784), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.334073750000002, longitude: -122.02357465), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.334120370000001, longitude: -122.0235716), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.334169469999999, longitude: -122.02356758000001), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.334220510000002, longitude: -122.02356580999999), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.334273039999999, longitude: -122.02356597000001), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.334326740000002, longitude: -122.02356743999999), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.334379980000001, longitude: -122.02356723), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.334436080000003, longitude: -122.02356829), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.334504440000003, longitude: -122.02357289), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.334565410000003, longitude: -122.02357538), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.334625559999999, longitude: -122.02357759), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.334685870000001, longitude: -122.02357768), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.334747299999997, longitude: -122.02357773), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.33480909, longitude: -122.02357759), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.334872420000004, longitude: -122.02357723), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.334942730000002, longitude: -122.02357637), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.335018179999999, longitude: -122.023573), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.335095870000004, longitude: -122.02356672000001), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.335175319999998, longitude: -122.02355701), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.335259520000001, longitude: -122.02354482), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.335346260000001, longitude: -122.02352918), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.335435189999998, longitude: -122.02351114), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.335526700000003, longitude: -122.02348929), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.335615359999998, longitude: -122.02346115), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.335705070000003, longitude: -122.02342901999999), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.335796440000003, longitude: -122.02339327), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.33589113, longitude: -122.02335769), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.33598464, longitude: -122.02332491999999), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.336079929999997, longitude: -122.02329487999999), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.336179360000003, longitude: -122.02327117), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.336281159999999, longitude: -122.02325363999999), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.3363838, longitude: -122.02324118999999), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.336481880000001, longitude: -122.02323437), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.336578070000002, longitude: -122.02323232000001), __C.CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.336673759999996, longitude: -122.02322977999999)]
>   (lldb)`

and

```
 
self    fix_it_mapView.MapViewController    0x00007fb37980b000
trackingLatitude    CLLocationDegrees   37.333153109999998
trackingLongitude   CLLocationDegrees   -122.02360022000001
alertLatitude   CLLocationDegrees   
alertLongitude  CLLocationDegrees
```

The function from where `checkAlerts()` gets called does the printing of the arrays before calling it, but it seems that the call get performed before and I just can't find out whether it's a typo or else.

```
func stopTracking() {
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    let duration = daysLasted(start: dateStart, end: Date())
    print("tracking stopped")
    self.dataReceived = "bici rubata"

    self.endTrackingPoint.coordinate = (locationManager.location?.coordinate)!  // gets courrent user location and store it into end tracking point
    self.trackingRoute.append(self.endTrackingPoint)                            // append end poit to route array
    mapView.showAnnotations(trackingRoute, animated: true)  // shows start and end ponits only
    drawRoutePolyline()  //draw route
    print("alerts coordinates are\(alertNotificationArray)")
    print("route coordinates are\(trackingCoordinatesArray)")
    checkAlerts()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code is probably the issue since it allows `alertNotificationArrayPosition` to go up to be equal to `alertNotificationArray.count` which will mean an index out of range error,

```
 else if alertNotificationArrayPosition < alertNotificationArray.count {
    alertNotificationArrayPosition = alertNotificationArrayPosition + 1
 }
```

I also think the while condition looks very strange where you are using `!=` rather than `<` or `<=`

Comment: yes.. that was the problem, changed to
`else if alertNotificationArrayPosition < ((alertNotificationArray.count) - 1) {
            
            alertNotificationArrayPosition = alertNotificationArrayPosition + 1
            } `
I forgot the -1 in the `if else` statements. The != is not a problem, I just use it to avoid typos as >= instead of <= and vice versa, but a <= would do just the same.
Now I need to set a range for alertNotificationArray values so they don't have do be identical, sort of regions for `didEnterRegion`

Comment: I resolved the checking part using the `distance(from: coordinate)` method, and checkin if that distance would be <= 10 meters.
that would be the same that setting a circle of 10 meters radius and check id the user coordinates are within the circle boundaries.
looks promising.. a workaround to implement the same userDidEnterRegion functionality, but without the restriction of 20 regions. as alway thank you very much.